# Why an array of dictionaries needs initializing 2nd time

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<string, int>[] db_players = new Dictionary<string, int>[6];      

    public Form1()
    {
        db_players[0] = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
        db_players[0].Add("qwerty",7);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(db_players[0]["qwerty"].ToString());
    }
}
```

**db_players[0].Add()** doesnt wonna work without initializing it right there in the constructor. I don't understand why cause I've done it above. Why is that? Sorry for dumb question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying that the code shown here works, but it would not work if you removed the line `db_players[0] = new …;`? And you want to know why you need that particular line of code? To be sure, some detail questions: **1.** What are you referring to when you say _"initializing **it** right there in the constructor"_? **2.** What do you mean by _"… [doesn't] work?"_ What error do you get? A compilation error? A runtime exception? Which?

Comment: Thanks. Guys below clarified it

Comment: -1 for asking an unclear question and apparently not caring about improving its quality for others / future readers.

Comment: The question is settled and you can see 4 the same answers and I think it becomes obvious what I meant. Anyway sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  aren't creating a dictionary here.. your creating an **array** of dictionaries. In C# whenever you initialize an array you are not initializing its elements.

For more information, you can find this [Arrays Tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Within this link there is a note that states

> If you do not initialize an array at the time of declaration, the array members are automatically initialized to the default initial value for the array type

For reference types, this is null. Hence why your code won't work

Comment: What about an array of `int`?

Comment: Awesome! I think that's why OP is confused. Array initialisation differs between value and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring an **array of 6 dictionaries**. Each array element needs to be instantiated individually.

Either do what you do now, or inline-initialize them:

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] db_players = new Dictionary<string, int>[6] {
  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
  new Dictionary<string, int>()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] db_players = new Dictionary<string, int>[6];
```

Creates an array of `Dictionary<string, int>` with length 6, but it doesn't set what should be in `db_players[0]`, `db_players[1]`, ...

You can initialize the array with a loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<db_players.Length; i++)
{
    db_players[i] = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
}
```

If at all you need to initialize in one statement you can use array initializer syntax.

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] db_players = new Dictionary<string, int>[]
{
    new Dictionary<string, int>(),
    new Dictionary<string, int>(),
    new Dictionary<string, int>(),
    new Dictionary<string, int>(),
    new Dictionary<string, int>(),
    new Dictionary<string, int>()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this line `Dictionary<string, int>[] db_players = new Dictionary<string, int>[6];` declares and initialize a list of Dictionary arrays named db_players. It does not give db_players its value. Hence, you need `db_players[0] = new Dictionary<string, int>();` to assign a dictionary to each object in the array itself.